# Filesystem for external hard disk that is cross-platform compatible

Tags: hard-drive, external-disk, filesystem

All my previous backup disks are either ext3, ext4, ntfs or fat32. I am having tremendous difficulty accessing my files easily from my mac (even with tools such as Tuxera). I did not expect an OS to not support access open file systems!

So now comes the time to format a new external hard disk where I will keep copies of some of my files (no time machine, just copies of some of my files and maybe an rsync partition). I need to be able to read this disk easily from any linux machine. I suppose FAT32 would work, but it would not support large files. What is the best solution here?